# Jersey throwing Connection refused error after building and running on JRE 17

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, java-17, azul-zulu

Migrated application from `JRE-8` to `JRE-17`. Jar is build and ran on `JRE-17`. No code change was required. No clues why this exception occurs.
Jersey version is `2.35`. The same code works fine when build and ran on `JRE-8`

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:269) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:297) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:662) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390) ~[jersey-common-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:661) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:439) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:345) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
//removed the calling code here

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.handleException(HttpUrlConnector.java:549) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:375) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:267) ~[jersey-client-2.35.jar!/:?]
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Is there any other stacktraces that showed up before this one? Also, try running with `-Dsun.reflect.debugModuleAccessChecks=true`

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueHupner updated the stacktrace. Do you want me to run gradle build with above options Or run java application with that parameter ?

Comment: Ran the gradlew with `-Dsun.reflect.debugModuleAccessChecks=true` to build the jar but the same error persist.

Comment: Which update of JDK 8 were you using? Don't know if this is the solution, but after update 291 (April 2021), TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are disabled by default (as they are in JDK 17). I've seen network errors like this caused by that. Change the JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security file to re-enable.

Comment: we were using `8_21_0_2`. Btw connection is made on http and not on https.